# link error, how it happens?

Tags: c++, struct, declaration

i have two files, `utility.h` and `utility.cpp`.  i declare a struct `BoundingSphere` in the .h file

```
struct BoundingSphere
{
    BoundingSphere();
    D3DXVECTOR3 _center;
    float _radius;
};
BoundingSphere::BoundingSphere()
{
    _radius = 0;
}
```

if i put the `BoundingSphere::BoundingSphere()` implementation into the .h file, i get a link error, error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall BoundingSphere::BoundingSphere(void)" already defined in bounding.obj

but, if i put the implementation into .cpp file, it works ok.
my question is that how it could happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because your first code example breaks the **[One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)**.

When you include the definition in the header file the precompiler merely copy pastes the content of the header in every translation unit where you include the header.
What you end up with is multiple definitions of the same function, this breaks the One Definition rule and hence the linker error.

If you need to add definitions in the header file then you need to mark the function as `inline`. Though you should note that request to `inline` a function is merely a suggestion to the compiler and it is free to accept or reject it.

Comment: you mean i can not implement a function in a .h file if it is not a inline function?

Comment: @cloud: No you cannot.Also, You should `inline` functions only if they have trivial implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Als tells the truth (not the whole truth, though), but to answer *your* question: if you put the implementation into `.h` file, then you have it in object files compiled from each source that includes the header. Therefore, you have multiple definitions. If you put it into `.cpp` file, then it is defined only once in that file.

Comment: actually, i add the precompile command `#ifndef __d3dUtilityH__#define __d3dUtilityH__`, i thought that would make the .h file included only once, is't it?

Comment: @Als, your answer was much shorter when I wrote it. But I was mostly referring to your use of keyword-formatted `inline`. Inline definition inside class would have similar effect.

Comment: @cloud, that would mean that you won't have it twice in the same unit.